# Why is main method not getting called same no. of times recursively in java every time it is executed?

Tags: java

When I tried to run this program  couple of times the final value of `i` is `11407`, `11417`, `11400` etc. before displaying stack overflow error. Why is the final value of `i` not same every time this program is executed?

```
public class MainRecursive {
    static int i=0;

    public static void main (String arg[])
    {
        i++;
        System.out.println(i);

        main(arg);
    }
}
```

Comment: @nobalG it's nothing to do with that - the OP is querying why the stack overflow condition is not _deterministic_.

Comment: Well that's a completely spurious close vote - `static` has absolutely nothing to do with this.

Comment: Interesting. For me the values are roughly `10813` through `10820`.

Comment: Yes, it is an interesting question - I had no idea that a stack overflow might be non-deterministic.  It's not as if there should be much (if any?) garbage collection going on, either.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes.why this behaviour in the result?According to what factors is the result varying?

Comment: @UmaKalyani: I have no idea. Like you and Alnitak, I would expect this to be consistent. I'm sure it *is* deterministic, but I don't know what the variables are that make it inconsistent.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it would be interesting to find out whether that `println` call is somehow triggering some non-deterministic GC behaviour, but without it I can't see an obvious way to record the recursion count...

Comment: @Alnitak: Doesn't seem to be the `println`, I continue to get inconsistent results with this: http://pastie.org/9699784 (the final `i` is a lot higher and a lot more variable, though, in the 20326 - 22093 range).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder heh, it never occurred to me that you could actually `catch` a `StackOverflowError` :)

Comment: @UmaKalyani: If you think [this update to that code](http://pastie.org/9699784) (which also shows the variability, but without the `println`) would enhance the question, I'd suggest adding it. I felt it was too much of a change to just go ahead and do myself.

Answer (score 3):

Try to add `System.out.flush();` after printing.

Since the stack size is not changing, i gets to the same value each time you run, but I think `println()` gets interrupted by the exception before it updates the output at different times - this depends on the console, operating system etc and cannot be deterministic.

Comment: The result is same .Anyways thanks for your response

Comment: Cofirmed! After adding flush I get consistent 10821

Comment: Nice idea, but I'm actually not getting consistent results, using Java 1.8.0_20 on MacOS X 10.10

Comment: Here too. Doing that changes the final value I get for `i`, but doesn't make it consistent. Good thought, but not the answer.